# How to change the text in a span within an html string?

Tags: jquery, string, text

I got as far as knowing that strings are immutable objects in jquery, but that is not helping me solve this problem.

This is a simplified version. We got a table row. I need to change the text in the span id "rptRepeater_lblMiddleName_0" from "William" to "W."

What's the best approach to do this?

We have tried html, text, but it seems that we cannot change the string.

```
function GetChangedMiddleName {

var strTableRow = '<tr><td><span id="rptRepeater_lblFirstName_0">John</span></td><td><span id="rptRepeater_lblMiddleName_0">William</span></td><td><span id="rptRepeater_lblLastName_0">Smith</span></td></tr>'

$(strTableRow).find('[id*=_lblMiddleName_]').text('W.');

return strTableRow;
}
```

The result should be:

```
'<tr><td><span id="rptRepeater_lblFirstName_0">John</span></td><td><span id="rptRepeater_lblMiddleName_0">W.</span></td><td><span id="rptRepeater_lblLastName_0">Smith</span></td></tr>'
```

Comment: You need to store the modified value back into `strTableRow`

Comment: we tried 
strTableRow = $(strTableRow).find('[id*=_lblMiddleName_]').text('W.'); 
but strTableRow now would point to a span object

Comment: Do you really need a **string** result?

Comment: There was also a typo in your function definition.  Missing the `()` on the function.

Answer (score 1):

You can change it, call `end()` to revert the finder, then get the outerHTML to store back into the variable.

```js
function GetChangedMiddleName() {

  var strTableRow = '<tr><td><span id="rptRepeater_lblFirstName_0">John</span></td><td><span id="rptRepeater_lblMiddleName_0">William</span></td><td><span id="rptRepeater_lblLastName_0">Smith</span></td></tr>'

  strTableRow = $(strTableRow).find('[id*=_lblMiddleName_]').text('W.').end().prop('outerHTML');

  return strTableRow;
}


console.log(
  GetChangedMiddleName()
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

When parsing fragments like that, you're probably better off with `$.parseHTML()` than `$()`.

When you're done, either return the elements resulting from parsing, or if you *have* to convert back to HTML, you can use `outerHTML` on the row to do that, see comments:

```js
function GetChangedMiddleName() {

    var strTableRow = '<tr><td><span id="rptRepeater_lblFirstName_0">John</span></td><td><span id="rptRepeater_lblMiddleName_0">William</span></td><td><span id="rptRepeater_lblLastName_0">Smith</span></td></tr>'

    // Parse the HTML
    var result = $($.parseHTML(strTableRow));
    
    // Do the update
    result.find('[id*=_lblMiddleName_]').text('W.');

    // If you can just return the parsed result, do that
    // return result;
    
    // If it has to be a string, use outerHTML on the row to get the string
    return result[0].outerHTML;
}
console.log(GetChangedMiddleName());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is much better than only working with string, and as we are changing quite a bunch of control contents, then it works best. Thanks a lot!